# Multi select ListPreference on android

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

Any idea on implementing a multi-select (check boxes) ListPreference on Android?

Would I have to extend the ListPreference?
Is there any classes already documented to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a very useful link: 
http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240

Comment: The link is dead.  Can the content still be found somewhere?

Comment: found this cached page from google if it's help: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240

Comment: Do not simply add links as answers; links can expire. Instead please add important block from the link along with it.

Comment: Internet Wayback Machine has a capture of it: [https://web.archive.org/web/20100406030947/http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240](https://web.archive.org/web/20100406030947/http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240), with the [source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20100408020225/http://blog.350nice.com:80/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/listpreferencemultiselect.java) and everything.

Answer (score 22):

Multi select ListPreference now comes natively with Android from API level 11 (Honeycomb).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.html

Because it will be quite a while before devices have Honeycomb or later installed I'd recommend people to stick with the  http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240 solution.

EDIT: I think at this moment in time (almost 3 years after this answer was originally posted) you are better off using the native version now as the majority of devices have Android 4 and up.

Comment: Many developers, myself included, would prefer not to lock out a still significant segment of users by increasing our minSdkVersion from 10 to 11. What I don't understand is what is the need for all these solutions, github projects posted in other answers, etc? Are we not forgetting that Android is open source. If you want to target API 10+, just grab the actual source code for the MultiSelectListPreference and be done with it, e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.java

Answer (score 10):

Well , http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240 does provide a solution , but a simpler solution would be just implementing a child preference screen inside the parent , and then the child preference screen can have multiple check boxes . I know , its not the best solution , but gets the job done .

For eg - the Below preference.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Regular messages"
    android:key="regular_messages">

    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="enable_regular_messages"
        android:summary="Enable or disable regular messages"
        android:title="Send regular messages" 
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />

    <ListPreference 
        android:key="send_interval"
        android:title="Send interval"
        android:summary="Define how often you want to send messages"
        android:defaultValue="60000" 
        android:entries="@array/send_interval"
        android:entryValues="@array/send_interval_values"
        android:dependency="enable_regular_messages"
    />

 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:title="Messages type"
     android:key="messages_type"
     android:summary="Select the type of messages to be sent"
     android:dependency="enable_regular_messages">
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="enable_status_messages"
        android:summary="Enable or disable status messages"
        android:title="Send status messages" 
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />

    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="enable_event_messages"
        android:summary="Enable or disable event messages"
        android:title="Send event messages" 
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />

    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="enable_critical_messages"
        android:summary="Enable or  disable critical messages"
        android:title="Send critical messages" 
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />

    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a single-class implementation with `defaultValue` support:
https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/develop/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/widget/MultiSelectListPreference.java

Comment: It works well. I would add this method to the code, so that you don't need to import it:  public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

There is a [github project](https://github.com/h6ah4i/mulsellistperfcompat) just for this