# Checkbox with many tickable items in preference android

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-checkbox

I need a setting in my application where the user can select the days he wants to receive notifications. I have taken a look at `CheckBoxPreferences` but it doesn't seem to be able to solve my problem. What I want is, when a user clicks on the setting, a dialog should open displaying Monday to Sunday, and the user should check zero or more of these.

How can I implement this?

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593037/multi-select-listpreference-on-android) - possible duplicate.

Comment: I could not find MultiSelectListPreference, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's since API Level 11. But there are alternatives, if you're supporting older devices. They are illustrated in the post I linked.